# Playing still images as a video in AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avqueueplayer

I want to play a sequence of videos and images (like Snapchat does). By playing an image I mean having it show on the screen for a certain amount of time. I am using `AVFoundation` for media capture and playback, and I am using **swift** to develop this application. 
I have `.mp4` videos and `.jpg` images, and I was trying to think of the easiest way to convert the `.jpg` images to videos such that I could simply add everything to the array of assets that will be passed in as a parameter to the `AVQueuePlayer` initializer.

Does anybody have any insight on how to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?